# Sinon Spy not registering it has been called(Async/Await)

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, sinon

When I run the test "Should call getDetails()" it fails with the message stating that the function was called 0 times. If I log the spy I can see that it its prop 'called' is equal to false. I know it is being called because I have a `console.log` in `getDetails` and it shows up each time `getMultipleRecords()` is called. The first test works just fine but `findAll()` is a promise, so I know it is an async issue.

I believe the issue is with mocha not respecting the `await`. Anyone's feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Test:

```js
describe('getMultipleRecords()', () => {
  let next = () => {};
  let req = { body: { records: [1, 2, 3] } };
  let res = {};

  // Passing
  it('Should call VMBilling.findAll()', async function() {
    var findAll = sinon.spy(VMBilling, 'findAll');

    await recordCtrl.getMultipleRecords(req, res, next);

    //console.log(find)
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(findAll);
  });

  // Failing
  it('Should call getDetails()', async function() {
    var gd = sinon.spy(recordCtrl, 'getDetails');

    await recordCtrl.getMultipleRecords(req, res, next);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(gd);
  });
});
```

Function that I am testing

```
const getMultipleRecords = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log('getMultipleRecords()');
    let records = await VMBilling.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: ErrorMessage,
        },
      ],
      where: [
        {
          id: req.body.records,
        },
      ],
    });

    let recordsWithDetails = getDetails(records);
    console.log(recordsWithDetails);
    return res.status(200).json(recordsWithDetails);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because after compilation the functions are exported with different signatures, with full name and while stubbing we stub the global function but while calling it from within the other function, we call the local function, hence it doesn’t work. There is a workaround to do that.

Here is the unit test solution:

`controller.ts`

```js
import { VMBilling } from './model';

const getDetails = records => {
  console.log(records);
};

const getMultipleRecords = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log('getMultipleRecords()');
    let records = await VMBilling.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: 'ErrorMessage'
        }
      ],
      where: [
        {
          id: req.body.records
        }
      ]
    });

    let recordsWithDetails = exports.getDetails(records);
    console.log(recordsWithDetails);
    return res.status(200).json(recordsWithDetails);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

exports.getMultipleRecords = getMultipleRecords;
exports.getDetails = getDetails;
```

`model.ts`:

```js
export const VMBilling = {
  findAll(conditions) {
    console.log('conditions');
  }
};
```

`controller.spec.ts`:

```js
import { VMBilling } from './model';
import sinon from 'sinon';
const recordCtrl = require('./controller');

describe('getMultipleRecords()', () => {
  let next = () => {};
  let req = { body: { records: [1, 2, 3] } };
  let res = {};
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  it('Should call VMBilling.findAll()', async function() {
    var findAll = sinon.spy(VMBilling, 'findAll');
    await recordCtrl.getMultipleRecords(req, res, next);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(findAll);
  });

  it('Should call getDetails()', async function() {
    var gd = sinon.spy(recordCtrl, 'getDetails');
    await recordCtrl.getMultipleRecords(req, res, next);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(gd);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
  getMultipleRecords()
getMultipleRecords()
conditions
undefined
undefined
    ✓ Should call VMBilling.findAll()
getMultipleRecords()
conditions
undefined
undefined
    ✓ Should call getDetails()


  2 passing (9ms)

--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files           |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 controller.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 controller.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 model.ts           |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58209098

Comment: Thank you this solves my problem. The major difference I found was that you changed getDetails() to exports.getDetails(). Why do you need to specify the module? When importing am I essentially creating a new instance and therefore in my tests I am referring to a different instance of getDetails()?

Comment: @austinb91 Update answer, please check.